# convert double to long without rounding in Kusto (KQL)

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

do you know how to convert double to long in kql without rounding down? i used tolong function but its rounding down i.e 0.38 -> 0. I'm looking for a way to return the same value and convert it to long.

Comment: you may want to clarify what the expected output for the input `0.38` is, if not `0`

Comment: i would like it to return the same value

Comment: you may want to clarify how `0.38` can be converted to `long` (an integer) and remain with the *same value*, i.e. `0.38` (not an integer) - perhaps it'd be easier if you provide a reference from a different query/programming language for comparison

Answer (score 1):

The `long` data type represents a signed, 64-bit wide, integer.
So 0.38 is simply not a `long`, and if you try to do the conversion, the value will be rounded down to the nearest integer value.

See more details in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/long).